# How do you calculate the transformation matrix for a camera?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I have a camera with the position, forward, right, and down vectors defined as class members `_position`, `_forward`, `_right`, and `_down`. For the rotation part of the problem, I simply load the rows of the destination coordinate system (view space) with `_forward`, `_right`, and `_down` and then apply a rotation matrix to go into "OpenGL" view space.

Before that I translate by the negative of `_position`. Is this correct, or do I need to do more math to determine the actual translation to pre- or post- multiply by my rotation?

Below is the code I have that doesn't seem to work. Specifically, I am rendering an object (a small quad facing down the z-axis) at the origin of world space and when I run the program that object appears distorted. (Note that the mat4 constructor takes elements in ROW major order though it stores them in column major internally).

```
mat4 Camera::matrix() const
{
    return
        mat4(
            0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) *
        mat4(
            _forward.x, _forward.y, _forward.z, 0.0f,
            _right.x, _right.y, _right.z, 0.0f,
            _down.x, _down.y, _down.z, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) *
        translate(
            -_position.x,
            -_position.y,
            -_position.z
        );
}
```

Here is the code for the look at function that is being used before the above.

```
void Camera::look_at(const vec3& position, const vec3& point)
{
    _position = position;
    _forward = normalize(point - position);
    _right = cross(_forward, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    _down = cross(_forward, _right);
}
```

In my initialization, I use this code:

```
camera.look_at(vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
view = camera.matrix();
proj = perspective(60.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH / (float)SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.001f, 100.0f);
view_proj = proj * view;
```

Comment: You could get rid of the first matrix multiplication by just re-ordering the middle matrix and assigning `-` where necessary. Should probably be `(right, -down, -forward)`. What exactly does not seem to work? The general idea looks good. The rest depends on your definition of coordinate systems.

Comment: Doesn't this mean your constructor takes in parameters in column major order? "The mat4 constructor takes elements in ROW major order (though it stores them in column major internally)" In your example _forward is a column vector in the matrix, right? It just looks like row major ordering because you can't actually write them like they're in columns.

Comment: Also, is the `matrix()` method trying to get the lookAt matrix, or the model matrix of the camera? (The difference is that the lookAt matrix is the inverse of the model matrix, used to transform objects from world space to camera space)

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Thanks. You're right that I could get rid of the first matrix which would make this faster. I wrote it that way so that it was clearer to a third party what was going on, but if I did it your way I would expect such a third party to understand why forward/right/down would need to be reordered for OpenGL. As for what doesn't work is that the image produced seems distorted. Thanks to the answer below I realize that in my look_at function (which I added to the question) does not normalize all the vectors, so I'll have to try that later today when I can work on the project.

Comment: @MatthewWoo: Thanks for your help. The parameters to the mat4 constructor are row major (m0, m4, m7, m12, m1, m5, m9, m13, etc.) but are written to the internal 1d float array as m[0] = m0, m[1] = m1, etc. (i.e. column major) unless I am using these terms row/column major wrong I believe this is correct for the purpose of readability (a list of matrix elements can be formatted correctly in a text editor if they are specified in row major).

The Camera::matrix() method is supposed to return the view matrix, i.e. the worldToView matrix. So it should return the inverse of the viewToWorld matrix

Comment: Ok, fair enough. However, in my opinion, it is much clearer to specify which vector goes in which column (or row). Otherwise, you had to fiddle out what this rotation is actually doing. Something like "forward goes to -z; right goes to +x..." is pretty clear to me. In fact, the order forward, right, down seems just arbitrary to me.

Comment: @Brynn Mahsman oh I see. I guess the row-major/column-major makes sense, it was just tripping me up because a mixture of row/column major screws up a lot of things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `glm::lookAt()` for convenience.

For more info refer https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00245.html#ga2d6b6c381f047ea4d9ca4145fed9edd5

But here is how one would construct it from position, target and up vectors.

note this is same as the lookAt() function.

```
//creates a lookat matrix
mat4 lookAt(Vec3 eye, Vec3 center, Vec3 up)
{
    Vec3 left, up2, forward;

    // make rotation matrix

    // forward vector
    forward = center - eye;
    forward.Normalize();

    // up2 vector (assuming up is normalized)
    up2 = up;

    // left vector = up2 cross forward
    left = up2.Cross(forward);

    // Recompute up2 = forward cross left (in case up and forward were not orthogonal)
    up2 = forward.Cross(left);

    // cross product gives area of parallelogram, which is < 1.0 for
    // non-perpendicular unit-length vectors; so normalize left, up2 here
    left.Normalize();
    up2.Normalize();

     mat4(
        left.x, left.y, left.z, left.Dot(-eye),
        up2.x, up2.y, up2.z, up2.Dot(-eye),
        -forward.x, -forward.y, -forward.z, -forward.Dot(-eye),
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)

}
```

note that up2 = up in case up and forward were orthogonal, else up2 is an orthogonal up vector to forward.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added my look_at code to the question. Reading your implementation of lookAt made me realize I forgot to normalize the computed _right and _down vectors. Also, I notice that you load the translation part of the matrix not with -eye but with a linear combination of the rows (the rotation part) and -eye (i.e. left.Dot(-eye), up2.Dot(-eye), -forward.Dot(-eye). I will have to try this tonight when I have time to work on the code. Can you please tell me why it is the latter (linear combination) and not the former (-eye)?

Comment: After thinking about the problem a bit more, I realize that the code you provided creates a matrix that _rotates_ and then _translates_, while my code (seemingly incorrectly) tries to _translate_ and then _rotate_. Any affine transformation matrix times a 4-component vector is first a rotation (linear combination of the rows of the affine matrix and the input vector) and then a translation (offset by the last column of the affine matrix).

Comment: If you have the basis vectors of your destination coordinate system (camera space) relative to your source coordinate system (world space) _and_ the origin of your destination relative to your source (camera position in world space), then the matrix to go from source to destination is the destination basis as rows and _then_ a translation into correct position by the vector from destination origin to source origin _relative_ (rotated) to the destination basis. Thus why the -eye vector is transformed into camera space via dot products in your code and _then_ loaded into the last column.

Comment: Yes,  I simplified the matrix multiplications into 1 step just to reduce the number of lines.  It does make understanding the underlying math a bit hard, but is probably slightly more efficient. rotation then translation  is clearly the intention here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of calculating the view matrix (the answer to the specific question "How do you calculate the transformation matrix for a camera?") is the problem of transforming vectors and points from world space to view space. This is the same as transforming from any *source* space to a *destination* space. (For the rest of this answer, *source space* refers to world space and *destination space* refers to view space.) We are given the destination basis vectors (the rotation vectors) relative to source (the `_right` x, `_up` y, and `_backward` z camera vectors as `vec3`s) and the destination space's origin relative to source space (the `_position` point as a `vec3`). While the question uses `_forward`, `_right`, and `_down`, first we will look at `_right`, `_up`, and `_backward` to stay consistent with OpenGL view space. At the end we will look at the solution using the former vectors. In addition, the term *space* will refer to a a coordinate system basis (orientation vector) *and* and a frame origin (position vector).

The transformation matrix from a source space to a destination space can be formulated as a rotation so that all vectors and points are oriented correctly with respect to destination space, and then a translation so that all points are positioned correctly with respect to destination space. Any transformation matrix times a point is always a rotation (a linear combination of the rows of the matrix and the vector) and a translation (offsetting the result of the rotation by the fourth column vector). Note that a direction vector (denoted in homogeneous coordinates by the fourth component of the vector being set to zero) is not affected by the translation. We will now look at two methods to derive such a matrix, where the second method is computationally more efficient.

Let the offset vector be the vector that points the entire distance from the destination space to the source space. The first method, which is used in the code snippet provided by the question, is to first translate by the offset vector relative to source space. This operation repositions all points (but not vectors) to have the destination origin as their reference point. Second, a rotation is applied by loading into the first three columns the basis vectors of destination space relative to source space as rows (i.e. `_right`, `_up`, and `_backward`). Why rows? Vectors with respect to any coordinate system simply represent a linear combination of the underlying basis vectors of the coordinate system, and the result of a 4x4 matrix times a 4-component vector is simply a linear combination of the rows of the first matrix times the columns of the second matrix (in the case of a column vector, this is simply a 4x1 matrix). That linear combination is precisely what we're after and why homogeneous coordinates work. The following is sample code that implements this method. Note that the `translate()` function returns a translation matrix.

```
mat4 Camera::matrix() const
{
    return
        mat4(
               _right.x,    _right.y,    _right.z, 0.0f,
                  _up.x,       _up.y,       _up.z, 0.0f,
            _backward.x, _backward.y, _backward.z, 0.0f,
                   0.0f,        0.0f,        0.0f, 1.0f) *
        translate(
            -_position.x,
            -_position.y,
            -_position.z
        );
}
```

The second, more efficient method is to, instead of multiply two matrices, generate the matrix directly and avoid the need to multiply a rotation matrix and a translation matrix. First, as before, the first three columns are loaded with the destination basis vectors as rows. Finally, the translation vector (the first three elements in the fourth column) is calculated using the dot product of each of the basis vectors.

```
mat4 Camera::matrix() const
{
    return mat4(
           _right.x,    _right.y,    _right.z, -dot(   _right, _position),
              _up.x,       _up.y,       _up.z, -dot(      _up, _position),
        _backward.x, _backward.y, _backward.z, -dot(_backward, _position),
               0.0f,        0.0f,        0.0f,                      1.0f);
}
```

Note that the dot products should be `dot(_right, -_position)` etc., but we can save multiplications by moving the negation outside of the dot product to be `-dot(_right, _position)`.

These dot products are exactly the same as multiplying the rotation matrix by the translation matrix previously. For example, the following matrix multiplication demonstrates the situation in the first method. Compare it to the code above with the dot products.

```
| x0 x1 x2 0 |   | 1 0 0 -t0 |   | x0 x1 x2 -(x0*t0 + x1*t1 + x2*t2) |
| y0 y1 y2 0 |   | 0 1 0 -t1 |   | y0 y1 y2 -(y0*t0 + y1*t1 + y2*t2) |
| z0 z1 z2 0 | * | 0 0 1 -t2 | = | z0 z1 z2 -(z0*t0 + z1*t1 + z2*t2) |
|  0  0  0 1 |   | 0 0 0   1 |   |  0  0  0                       1  |
```

Note that at all times, the `_right`, `_up`, and `_backward` vectors (or `_forward`, `_right`, and `_down` vectors as in the question) must be normalized or else some unintentional scaling will result.

To account for using `_forward`, `_right`, and `_down` vectors an additional rotation needs to be applied to get to OpenGL view space. This matrix is listed below:

```
|  0  1  0  0 |
|  0  0 -1  0 |
| -1  0  0  0 |
|  0  0  0  1 |
```

The rows in the upper left 3x3 submatrix are the basis vectors of the OpenGL view space (right x, up y, backward z) relative to the desired camera space (forward x, right y, down z). We then multiply this matrix with the matrix from before with the dot products. Such a matrix multiplication is similar to:

```
|  0  1  0  0 |   | x0 x1 x2 t0 |   |  y0  y1  y2  y3 |
|  0  0 -1  0 |   | y0 y1 y2 t1 |   | -z0 -z1 -z2 -t2 |
| -1  0  0  0 | * | z0 z1 z2 t2 | = | -x0 -x1 -x2 -t0 |
|  0  0  0  1 |   |  0  0  0  1 |   |   0   0   0   1 |
```

The final matrix function could then be:

```
mat4 Camera::matrix() const
{
    float tx =  dot(_forward, _position);
    float ty = -dot(_right, _position);
    float tz =  dot(_down, _position);

    return mat4(
           _right.x,    _right.y,    _right.z,   ty,
           -_down.x,    -_down.y,    -_down.z,   tz,
        -_forward.x, -_forward.y, -_forward.z,   tx,
               0.0f,        0.0f,        0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

So it appears besides some performance issues, all the code in the question is correct except for the fact that the vectors *are not* normalized in the `look_at()` function.

Comment: What vectors need to be normalized? `_position` is just a position; `_forward` is normalized; `_right` is a cross product of 2 unit vectors, thus a unit vector; and same with `_down`. Unless you're implying that floating point precision is the problem here?

Comment: @MatthewWoo The cross product of two unit vectors will only have unit length iff the operands are perpendicular. In general, the length will be `sin(phi)`, where `phi` is the angle between the vectors.